# three20 error after adding it to my project

Tags: iphone, linker, three20

I have been trying to add the Three20 framework to my app. But I always end up getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
"___restore_vfp_d8_d15_regs", referenced from:
+[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) sharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
+[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) releaseSharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
+[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) allocWithZone:] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
"___save_vfp_d8_d15_regs", referenced from:
+[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) sharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
+[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) releaseSharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
+[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) allocWithZone:] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it seems like some kind of linker error to me, but I'm rather shure I followed all instructions on how to install the framework.
Somehow I get the suspicion, that it is a bug within the framework, but I'm not shure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that, in the build settings, you've selected 'Standard' for the architectures and that 'Build Active Architecture Only' is unchecked.

Comment: I checked. Both settings were as you suggest them.

Comment: As I had the same problem with device building and I googled for it and I got the above solution which solves the building problem with device.

Comment: Ok, I got it working now. The trick is to set this in each and every project of Three20. additionally I've set the BaseSDK to iPhone Device, instead of Simulator. I suppose this helped, too. Once again not only in my app, but in every part of Three20.